# Get Data from 2 Tables using Join

Tags: postgresql, join

I have 2 tables :

```
1. transfer
2. data
```

in table data 2 records :

```
   id   name
1.  2   PQR
2.  3   XYZ
```

in table transfer 5 records :

```
    id   to   from   amount   type
1.   1    2      3   100.00    C
2.   2    3      2   200.00    C
3.   3    2      3   150.00    D
4.   4    3      2   150.00    C 
5.   5    2      3   300.00    D
```

now I want to form query that will take `2` in where condition and give me result
from transfer table that when `2` is in `to` column then `from` data should be shown
and when `2` is in `from` column then `to` data should be print.
And in result I want other columns that are amount and type.
I want data using `join (Any)`, I am totally confused that how to perform this task.

**Expected Result :**

```
from/to  amount  type
  3      100.00   C
  3      200.00   C
  3      150.00   D
  3      300.00   D
```

Any Guidance on this..

Comment: You should really rethink your naming scheme. A good naming scheme makes things much more clear and then the solutions to your problems come much easier. Not to mention other people being able to understand your question better when you post it to StackOverflow. Also, can you post an example of what your final result set should look like?

Comment: post example result want you want?

Comment: I have updated question with expected result.

Comment: from/to is a single column ah?

Comment: previously you wanted `2`, now you expect `3`..? @@

Comment: this is the main confusion for me that's why I have put question on STO, if 2 is in from then to's data display and if 2 is in to then from data display, so that's why I have used like that, means I want opposite column data.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 : I have told that when I pass 2 data should be opposite column i.e. `3`.

Comment: okay, I see.. got it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
select 
case when "from"=2 then "to" when "to"=2 then "from" end "from/to"
,amount,type from transfer
```

Out put is

```
 form/to     amount   type

  3          100      C
  3          200      C
  3          150      D
  3          150      C
  3          100      D
```

OR

```
 select case when "from"=2 then d.name when "to"=2 then data.name end "from/to",
 amount,type from transfer inner join data on ("to"=data.id) 
 inner join data as d on("from"=d.id)
```

Out put is

```
form/to     amount   type

  XYZ         100      C
  XYZ         200      C
  XYZ         150      D
  XYZ         150      C
  XYZ         100      D
```

**ADDITION**:
prove of working query: http://ideone.com/64kIov

Comment: Sir, I want it using Join, so When I pass 2 then that should be from table `data` and then it ll goes to `transfer`.

Comment: it's actually pretty straightforward.. have you tried it by yourself..?

Comment: when I remove that from there then query executes and display result but the main thing it's not show that is from or to, I have tried to put field name there but shows me an error : `syntax error near "from/to"` or `syntax error near to`

Comment: It's show column header `case` and in that all rows are blank. other data display.

Comment: do you want to show name of from/ to or id value (that means it show in transfer table) ah?

Comment: I want to show name, query : `select amount,case when "from"=2 then d.name when "to"=2 then data.name end,
 type from transfer inner join data on ("to"=a1.id) 
 inner join data as d on("from"=d.id)`

Comment: second show what kind of error. show that query. because its work fine for me

Comment: I hope you can learn a lot from here..
try to check once again, compare with this: http://ideone.com/64kIov
you might need to check some double quotes..

Comment: change like this `select amount,case when "from"=2 then d.name when "to"=2 then data.name end as fromorto,  type from transfer inner join data on ("to"=data.id)   inner join data as d on("from"=d.id)`

Comment: OK now working, have some table problem. Your query is perfect man. thank You So much for helping me.